# Vim imap using quotes can't work

Tags: vim

In my vimrc these work fine:

```
imap [ []<ESC>i
imap { {}<ESC>i
imap ( ()<ESC>i
imap < <><ESC>i
```

But the following doesn't seem to work:

```
imap " ""<ESC>i
imap ' ''<ESC>i
imap ` ``<ESC>i
```

Instead they seem to "kill" my vim, and I'm unable to do anything except for killing the terminal.

Comment: If you get caught out by a recursive mapping you can stop it by hitting `CTRL-C`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at the `noremap` option:

```
inoremap " ""<ESC>i
```

It's usually a good idea to make every mapping not recursive.

Ref: `:h :nore`